# grunt inject file tree into javascript object

Tags: file, tree, gruntjs, inject

Is there a way to use Grunt to read the structure of a file tree into a JSON object, then inject it into a javascript file.

For example, lets say my project had a file with structure...

```
Assets
  ├╴docs                             
  │ └╴doc1.txt  
  │ └╴doc2.txt                  
  │ 
  ├╴effects 
  │ └╴sound.mp3
```

I would be able to inject into some .js file.

```
Assets = { 
  docs : ['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt.'],
  effects: [sound.mp3]       
}
```

where initial assets equals some while card, like '@@injectHere'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I figured this out as a two step process.

**First**, I grunt-tree module to build a JSON representation of the file system.  I save the JSON file to a temporary file in the .tmp folder.

```
tree: {
  options: {
  },
  soundFileTree: {
    files: [
        {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/audio/'],
            dest: '.tmp/soundTree.json',
        }
    ],
  },
},
```

**Second**, I inject the JSON file into my final destination.

I use grunt-injector module.  I simply used require() inside the transform() function option to read the JSON from the .tmp folder.  If you require() a JSON file, it will return a JSON object.  So my grunt file looks like this...

```
injector: {
      // Inject JSON file into client and server files
      soundFileTree: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            var soundTreeJSONString = require(filePath); //you might have to adjust the files path
            return JSON.stringify(soundTreeJSONString);
          },
          starttag: '/* injector:soundFileTree */',
          endtag: '/* endinjector */',
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/treeTarget.js': ['.tmp/soundTree.json'],
        },
      }, 
   ...
}
```

My destination file looks like this (not the actual folders and files are different than in my question.

```
var myVar=
/* injector:soundFileTree */
{"boxing":{"bell":"boxing/bell.wav","warning":"boxing/warning.wav"}}
/* endinjector */
;
```